# Mysql Connection Lost due to execution of JOIN Query

Tags: mysql, join, database-connection

I have written following query but due to large number of rows at stock_prices; mysql throws Connection Lost Error: So query is correct but we require optimized one.
**Query**:

```
SELECT l.symbol, l.companyname, s.closing, s.change_price, s.stock_return, s.volume
FROM listed_companies as l, stock_prices as s
WHERE l.symbol = s.symbol AND DATE(s.stock_date) = (**SELECT max(`stock_date`) as MaxDate FROM stock_prices WHERE l.symbol = symbol**)  
ORDER BY l.symbol
```

Here, stock_prices has large number of data and having multiple row of single value  corresponding to the  single row of listed_companies table.

Highlighted sub query creates issue and taking much execution time.

Suggest any Alternate Query.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
   SELECT l.symbol, l.companyname, s.closing, s.change_price, s.stock_return, s.volume
    FROM listed_companies as l, stock_prices as s
    WHERE l.symbol = s.symbol AND 
    ORDER BY l.symbol
```

2.

```
   SELECT l.symbol, l.companyname, s.closing, s.change_price, s.stock_return, s.volume
    FROM listed_companies as l, stock_prices as s
    WHERE  DATE(s.stock_date) = (**SELECT max(`stock_date`) as MaxDate FROM stock_prices WHERE l.symbol = symbol**)  
    ORDER BY l.symbol
```

Try to run both the query separately. Check whether both are giving results as per requirement. If yes then there may some issue with database. First try this out.